# analyzer with more than one Stem-filter for more languages

Tags: solr, solr4

It is possible to define an analyzer with more than one Stem-filter for more languages?

Something like this:

```
<analyzer type="index">
  …
  <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>  (default for english)
  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" />
</analyzer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it possible? for sure.

does it makes sense? probably not. One will run after the other, and the stemmed tokens by one will be processed by the other.

If by any chance the no modified token of PorterStemFilterFactory will be modified by Snowball (so only the ones that Porter did not touch are modified by it), it would work fine. But I doubt it.